# Selecting multiple items in lists in Android

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

I have an app where users are presented with a list of 10-15 items. They can pick up to for, so it's a multiple select use case. In iOS you would get a list, and you could tap on each list item, and you get the nice little checkmark on the right side. Very clean.

In Android, I believe the proper way to do it is to use the Contextual Action Bar, which tells you how many items you've selected. The list shows with checkboxes on the left.

Is this the proper Android pattern for this behavior?

I generally like Android patters, but this one feels clunky. I wondered if this was the only way to do it that Android users would find usable.

Comment: This is what you should use. I am not sure why you feel it is clunky, but most people find checkboxes a nice cue for selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, generally this is the Android pattern. You obviously don't *have* to follow it but Android users are generally used to this functionality.